# How do I get rid of the (ironic) ad in adblock?

Tags: google-chrome, adblock

In the new adblock plus for chrome, there's this message when you click the icon:

[image]

It's a bit ironic and is about the size of the entire options list. Very obtrusive.

How do I disable it? I can't use ABP to disable it.

I'm using [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=en) adblock.

Comment: That's ridiculous and indeed obtrusive. I'm using Adblock Plus in Chrome and I've never seen this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite annoying, and I see it less as ironic, and more as someone forgetting his target audience. I understand he does it for free, and needs donations, but an ad in the options page should have been enough.

So how do you get rid of it?

1. Open the folder where Chrome hosts the extensions files. 
   On a Mac that would be "~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions"
   In Windows that would be "C:\Documents and Settings\*UserName*\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions"
2. You're looking for the AdBlock extension folder, so locate a folder named "gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom"
3. Go in to "*version*/button" and open a page called popup.html for editing (any text editor would do)
4. Look for a section with the comment "CrowdFunding". You'd be tempted to delete it. Don't! This will cause JavaScript errors on page. 
   Instead, replace the following text:
   [image]
   with:

[image]

Make sure you've removed the "box" class!

Save the file. Try the popup now.

Comment: The file path for me was C:\Users\CMN573\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom\2.6.7_0 and the code wasn't matched, but I removed the ! from `if (1crowdfund.runningCampaign())`

Answer (score 0):

There's another solution, and i don't know if you like it, depends on how much you click on ad block.

I personally never click on it, i let it do its job, and therefore i don't need to see it, i right click on it and choose "hide button"

that way it won't show up, and if ever i need to add something to the options, i go to tools-> extensions-> adblock options

there's 1 day left to the campaign, hopefully we won't see it again.